# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a un vector existente en R?

Tags: r, bucles

He empezado usar R y estoy intentando crear un ciclo que vaya anexando diversos elementos a un vector o data frame existente. Intenté hacer la analogía de Python a R, sin embargo, no encuentro una manera de hacerlo.

Este es el código que yo crearía en Python para agregar los elementos del 1 al 10 a una lista vacía.

```
Lista=[]
for i in range (1,11):
    Lista.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay mucha diferencia con Python. Usamos una forma de ciclo que podemos llamar explícito:

```
Lista = list()
for(i in 1:10) {
  Lista = c(Lista, i)
}
```

Particularidades:

1. Creamos un objeto vacío `Lista` de tipo `list`
2. Con `for` recorremos un vector creado dinámicamente: `1:10`
3. Para agregar elementos a la lista, simplemente concatenamos cada uno con `c(Lista, i)`

Sin embargo, existe, al menos para este ejemplo, una forma mucho más compacta y más "natural" a R para hacer lo mismo:

```
Lista = lapply(1:10, c)
```

En este caso usamos un ciclo implícito, mediante `lapply()` que básicamente replica el ciclo `for` sobre el mismo vector, aplicando la misma función `c`.

Aclaración: uso como ejemplo un `list` ya que es lo que más se asemeja a una lista en Python.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La lógica usada es la misma. En vez de crear una lista, creas un vector nulo.

```
t<-c()
for (i in 1:10) {
  t<-c(t,i)
}
```

Luego aplicas el `for`, el iterador es el mismo, pero en la definición del recorrido es más sencillo en R. Sólo tienes que colocar desde 1 a 10 con `1:10`. Luego para guardar la iteración del `for` lo guardas en el vector nulo que creaste, pero usas la función `c` para concatenar los resultados.

A lo que te resulta

```
> t
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

También puedes hacer:

```
x <- 1:5
x1 <- 6:10

x <- c(x, x1)
```

Ahora el el vector "x" contiene los componentes de x más los de x1.